# How to get unit tests (using CMake and GTest) to know where a folder of test data is?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, c++17, googletest

I am using CMake and GTest to unit test a C++ program. One of my tests uses `fopen()` to open a file of test data.

I am struggling to figure out how to not get a "No such file or directory" error.

**Directory Structure**

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── src
│   └── myProgram.cxx
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── data
    │   ├── dataset1.txt
    │   ├── dataset2.txt
    │   ├── dataset3.txt
    │   └── dataset4.txt
    └── myProgramTests.cxx
```

**Test Code**

```
TEST(test, read_data_file) {
    // Open test file
    std::FILE *f = fopen("inputs/dataset1.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL){
        perror ("Error opening file");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

This seems simple, but I can't figure out what to put here. I have tried `"dataset1.txt"`, `"inputs/dataset1.txt"`, `"tests/inputs/dataset1.txt"`. What am I missing / is there a way for me into "include" these files via a line in `CMakeLists.txt` so I can just read them in with one of the strings I tried above?

**Summary**: How do I properly reference the location of files stored in a `tests/data` subdirectory within GTest?

Comment: I would also prefer to not do something like `"../../tests/data/dataset1.txt"` which I know does work (relative from the `build` folder)

Answer (score 3):

Use [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Testing%20With%20CMake%20and%20CTest.html) of cmake. Its [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html#add-test) command has a useful property [`WORKING_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/WORKING_DIRECTORY.html#prop_test:WORKING_DIRECTORY) that are you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Paths that do not start with a `/` are relative to your current working directory, i.e the directory your shell is in when you run the tests.

For example, if your current working directory is the top-level directory of your project, then the relative path to `dataset1.txt` is `tests/data/dataset1.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the note. Since this is GTest, the current working directory is the `build` directory. I was hoping there was a way to not have to write an ugly path like `"../../tests/data/dataset1.txt"`.

Comment: GTest does not enforce the current working directory, you're free to run the test binary from wherever you want.